# i'm trying to get this working but it shows errro at fileReader statement

Tags: java, filereader

this is the main class, it works for first step when i enter 1 or 2 for the next step it gives an error saying " error reading file

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1.Fraction Calculator");
    System.out.println("2.Grading Scheme");
    System.out.println("Enter Your Choice:");
    int ip = sc.nextInt();
    String frac1, frac2;
            // creating an object of Fraction class
    Grading grad=new Grading();
    grad.readFile();
    grad.calculateAverage();
    grad.calculateTestAvg();
    // creating an object of Fraction class
    Fraction frac =new Fraction();


    switch(ip){
        case 1: System.out.println("Enter two fractions:");
                //  input of the two fractions
                frac1 = sc.next(); frac2 = sc.next();
                // displaying the result table
                System.out.println("Addition: " + frac.add(frac1, frac2) + "\nSubtraction: " + frac.sub(frac1,frac2) + "\nMultiplication: " + frac.mul(frac1,frac2) + "\nDivision: " + frac.div(frac1, frac2));
                break; 

        case 2: grad.printGrades(); break;

        default : break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: get some IDE's like eclipse, netbean, intellij for development/learning....these will tell these errors for free. Text editor are good but they waste lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't handle java.io.FileNotFoundException,
you can throws that exception or use try catch block to handle it

**throws exception**

```
 void Grading()throws FileNotFoundException{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("score.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
}
```

**try-catch**

```
  void Grading(){

    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("score.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `throws FileNotFoundException` with `FileReader` so you have two option :

```
void Grading() throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("score.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
}
```

Or use `try{}catch(){}` :

```
void Grading() {
    FileReader fr;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("score.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        //...
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
}
```

**Edit**

don't forgot to import this libraries :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
```

Comment: i tried first option and it now gives error with saying" cannot find symbol"

Comment: @HarryKashyap maybe you don't import your libraries, check my edit now

Comment: ok now using the throw , eoor is gone but now programe is not working

Comment: what did you mean now working, share all your code please how you call this method?

Comment: @HarryKashyap this is wired, `Grading` is a method or a `class` ?

Comment: grading is a class

Comment: so how you call this method `void Grading() {` ?

Comment: public class Grading {

Comment: @HarryKashyap no i mean and why in the first example you use `void Grading() { ` can you please share all your code?

Comment: can i email you the whole project? o how can i show you the whole code?

Comment: sorry, i think your first problem is solved this can be another question @HarryKashyap ;)

Comment: damn, i have to submit it by today and it's not working

Comment: i'm sorry, your code is not clear enough @HarryKashyap